# const list = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']; type obj = { aa: any; bb: any; cc: any} We know list, and how to get type obj in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, interface

```
const list = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']; 
type obj = {   aa: any; bb: any; cc: any}
```

We have list. And how to get type obj in typescript

Comment: `type obj = { [k in typeof list[number]]: any };`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you declared `list` `as const` like so,

```
const list = ["aa", "bb", "cc"] as const;
```

or with this syntax,

```
const list = <const>["aa", "bb", "cc"];
```

you could define a type like this:

```
type Obj = { [K in typeof list[number]]: any };
```

If `list` is not declare `as const` I'm afraid it's impossible because you cannot access the actual array values in a type definition.